# Regular Expression With Mask

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression for phone numbers as follows:
 `^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$`

I have a mask on the phone number textbox in the following format: `(___)___-____`

How can I modify the regular expression so that it accommodates the mask?

Comment: Do you mean so it will also match the mask? Should it match the mask with part of it filled in, or only as "(_\_\_)___-____"?

Comment: It should also match the complete mask

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question, which was should it also match a partially filled in mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression for the (placeholder) mask is

`^\(_{3}\)_{3}-_{4}$`

---

The expression for a valid phone number is

`^\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$`

---

The mask uses `_` in place of digits, so you'll need to use `[\d_]` as your character class to match as the user is typing.

`^\([\d_]{3}\)[\d_]{3}-[\d_]{4}$`

---

Obviously, if the user switches fields, you'll want to return an error if your `phone` field as any remaining `_` in it. `phone.match(/_/) == null` should do the trick here :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear; if you want a regular expression that matches that mask, it's:

```
^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 1):

`ValidationExpression="\([2-9]\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\(_{3}\)\ _{3}-_{4}$"`

This will validate the mask and (234)432-4322 but won't allow the user to enter (434)88_-____

Answer (score 0):

this expression will work for you
^[( ][0-9][1-9][0-9][) ]?[0-9]{3}[- ]?[0-9]{4}$
 this expression defines that except second digit of phone number every digit will consider
{0}